# By the time of Star Wars: A New Hope, why was Leia familiar with Tarkin?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, princess-leia

When Leia is brought to the bridge of the Death Star, she clearly knows who Tarkin is, and clearly knows that he is just the kind of person to be involved in the Empire. What prior relationship do the two have?

Comment: She's a Senator and he's a major military leader in the Empire. It would be like Mitt Romney knowing who General Randy A. George is.

Comment: @Valorum He’s a governor. Also a Grand Moff (is that the military position?) and I think originally a Sith Lord before those were retconned. More like Alexandria Ocasio Cortez knowing who Greg Abbott is, IMHO.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Looks like Grand Moff had also military position - something like a viceroy of British Empire, perhaps? He was maybe the third most powerful man in Empire. All in all, I don't see how Leia could have *not* know who he was.

Comment: @ToddWilcox A Sith Lord? Got a citation for that? It sounds very interesting.

Comment: @Mithoron Not a military position, but they have executive authority over the military forces within the regions they govern. It’s just like how the provincial governors of the Roman Empire were not in a military position, but had authority over the military forces in their provinces.

Comment: @J.Mini Looks like I don't. I thought there was something about many people around that conference table being Sith Lords but either I'm imagining it or can't find it.

Comment: @ToddWilcox That would definitely change the vibe around the table.  Instead of only insulting the cybernetic death knight, Admiral Motti would be simultaneously insulting several other highly ranked people as well.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson I don't think the concept of Sith was originally related to Force use.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Leia has known about Tarkin from early childhood, and encountered him before she became a Senator.**

### Canon

> The very first thing Leia’s father had ever told her about Grand Moff
> Wilhuff Tarkin was that she was to stay away from him. **He had made an
> official visit to Alderaan right around the time Leia had turned
> thirteen—which,** coincidentally, was also about the time when Leia had
> made it her mission to do the opposite of whatever she was told to do.
> So she’d crept along the halls of the palace behind the two men,
> listening to the cold, tense words they exchanged.
>
> As she’d slipped out of her hiding place, one thought had blasted
> through her mind: he is a snake. A man who kept slaves. A man who
> wrapped around his victims and slowly, mercilessly crushed the life
> from them.
>
> <sub><sup>[A New Hope: The Princess, the Scoundrel, and the Farm Boy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/A_New_Hope:_The_Princess,_the_Scoundrel,_and_the_Farm_Boy)</sup></sub>

She subsequently *met* him at a function for apprentice legislators on Coruscant.

> Applause began as the guest speaker took the dais. It was a man Leia had never met before but one she had heard a great deal about…none of it good.
> [...]
> So many of the apprentice legislators were nervous to meet a grand
> moff. She observed that feeling without sharing it in the slightest;
> she had been no more than six the first time she met a king. While the
> others trembled, stammered, and shifted awkwardly from foot to foot or
> tentacle to tentacle, Leia stood straight, glad she’d braided her hair
> in a coil atop her head to provide the illusion of extra height, and
> waited her turn. When at last she was face to face with Grand Moff
> Tarkin, she took his hand with assurance. “Princess Leia Organa of
> Alderaan.”
>
> “Your Highness,” Tarkin said. His hand tightened around hers—only
> slightly more than would be customary, but enough that she felt he was
> holding her there. That lasted for only an instant, however, as did
> his brittle smile. “I look forward to discovering whether you’ll be
> the same kind of senator as your father.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Leia - Princess of Alderaan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Leia,_Princess_of_Alderaan)</sup></sub>

### Legends

> [image]
> [image]
> <sub><sup>[**The Princess Leia Diaries - Star Wars Tales #11**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Princess_Leia_Diaries)</sup></sub>

Comment: To be noted, that book was published in 2015.

Comment: @Stef - It was indeed. And as such, it's fully canon

Comment: My point is that Star Wars evolved a lot between the 1977 film and today; some things in the original film are pretty inconsistent with things that came later; so a 2015 novel retelling the story of the 1977 film is worth what it's worth, no more, no less, so I think it's important to mention the date. (The fact that this novel is  "canon" or "non canon" is certainly relevant as an internal Disney policy to decide what to stay consistent with and what not to stay consistent with when publishing new stuff, but not really relevant to the public deciding to read it or not).

Comment: @Stef - I've seen no indication that this conflicts with whatever canon existed before. Certainly there's nothing at the higher canon levels ("G-Canon", etc) that answers this question specifically.

Comment: FWIW, Back in 1977, when I saw the movie for the first time, I was not at all surprised by the idea that an adult "princess" whose father apparently ruled over some "kingdom" within a larger "empire" might know somewhat of the reputation of a key player in a plot to strip her family of their power.

Comment: To me, "canon" in the *Star Wars* universe has become arbitrary and changeable to the point that it doesn't really mean much. The validity of anything is more a matter of opinion.

Comment: Agreed with those saying that canon doesn’t really matter that much, since it's arbitrary "marketing policy" at this point. A better wording of the question might have been "when the script for Star Wars was written, how did Lucas suppose Leia knew Tarkin?". However, as a kid I never asked myself this question: it was obvious to me Tarkin was a major player/villain and everyone would know who he was.

Comment: But of course +1 because this answer is both canon and answers the question, even though it wouldn't answer my hypothetical rephrased question ;)

Comment: There's a similar backstory between the two in Legends. Unfortunately the Wookieepedia synopsis doesn't include the parts with Tarkin, but she drops a water balloon on his head: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Princess_Leia_Diaries

Comment: @MiloP - That will make a fine addition to my collection...

Comment: Dropping a water balloon on Tarkin and getting away with it! That is akin to Fred and George throwing snowballs at the back of Quirrell's head!

Answer (score 11):

He is a regional Governor of “numerous outlying Imperial territories”<sup>1</sup>. They are politicians who have served in the same government, more or less.

I suspect it’s similar to a federal legislator knowing a state or provincial executive of a rival political party.

1. *Star Wars* novelization, chapter III

Comment: Is there a relative ranking of Galactic Empire commanders/officials? It always seemed to me (without reading Wookieepedia, I value my sanity) that Tarkin was very high up in the hierarchy. I mean, he can boss Vader around! Much like second to the Emperor or close to that, anyway. So he would be well known.

Comment: @AndresF. Note that if you watch the first Star Wars film and no other material, it looks very much like Vader is just a general in the Empire, rather than the Emperor's direct apprentice and closest ally; and Tarkin appears to be the Death Star's commander, with authority over everyone aboard.